# htaccess rewrite and auth conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 directories each with a .htaccess file:

html/.htaccess - There is a rewrite in this file to send almost everything to url.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(exported/?|\.(php|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|pdf|doc|xml|ico))$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /url.php [L]
```

and html/exported/.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "exported"
AuthUserFile "/home/siteuser/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

If I remove html/exported/.htaccess the rewriting works fine and the exported directory can be access. If I remove html/.htaccess the authentication works fine.

However when I have both .htaccess files exported/ is being rewritten to /url.php. Any ideas how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have meant this for your regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^exported/?|\.(php|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|pdf|doc|xml|ico)$)
RewriteRule (.*)$ /url.php [L]
```

Does `html/exported/exported/` work in your current setup by any chance?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand, the '404' error occurs because Apache cannot find the '401 Authentication Needed' page. So I simply solved it by creating html/401.html, and adding

`ErrorDocument 401 /401.html`

to my html/.htaccess

Hint was taken from http://drupal.org/node/52465#comment-106353

Answer (score 1):

If none of above works for your scenario, Basic Authentication can also be done using php script

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['newlogin'])) { 
unset($_SESSION['newlogin']);
unset($_SESSION['loggedout']);
};
$valid_passwords = array ("admin" => "mypass");
$valid_apasswords = array ("admin" => "mypass");
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);
$valid_admin = array_keys($valid_apasswords);

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$avalidated = (in_array($user, $valid_admin)) && ($pass == $valid_apasswords[$user]);
$uvalidated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);
$validated = (($uvalidated == true) || ($avalidated == true)) ;

if (!$validated || isset($_SESSION['loggedout'])) {
        $_SESSION['newlogin'] = true;
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login Area"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="messagebox">Authorisation Required.</div>
</body>
</html>
        <?php
        exit;
};

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need any rewriting to occure in /html/exported/, why not to just turn off Rewriting engine in that folder:
RewriteEngine Off