# .htaccess mod-rewrite conflicting with subfolder auth

Tags: authentication, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site which redirects all requests for files/folders which don't exist to an index file using .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule !admin/* index.php [NC,L]
```

There is a folder "admin/" which has the following in .htaccess for auth:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Adding the auth .htaccess file in "admin/" causes the request to be trapped by mod-rewrite instead of providing the authentication response. I've tried a few different things trying to work around this (including this: [htaccess rewrite and auth conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641666/htaccess-rewrite-and-auth-conflict)), but couldn't get any purchase.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** If I'm already authenticated, the rewrite rule *works* allowing me to access the "admin/" folder. So it seems that it's the authentication challenge that's doing something wonky.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same question, and I also found this related question: [htaccess rewrite and auth conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641666/htaccess-rewrite-and-auth-conflict)

One of the answers there clued me into my problem.  Apache was trying to find a document for the 401 error and failing.  I added a document /401.html and added this to the .htaccess file with the Auth statements.

ErrorDocument 401 /401.html

Now, it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

If none of above works for your scenario, Basic Authentication can also be done using php script

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['newlogin'])) { 
unset($_SESSION['newlogin']);
unset($_SESSION['loggedout']);
};
$valid_passwords = array ("admin" => "mypass");
$valid_apasswords = array ("admin" => "mypass");
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);
$valid_admin = array_keys($valid_apasswords);

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$avalidated = (in_array($user, $valid_admin)) && ($pass == $valid_apasswords[$user]);
$uvalidated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);
$validated = (($uvalidated == true) || ($avalidated == true)) ;

if (!$validated || isset($_SESSION['loggedout'])) {
        $_SESSION['newlogin'] = true;
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login Area"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="messagebox">Authorisation Required.</div>
</body>
</html>
        <?php
        exit;
};

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say you tried the solution from the other post, what did your code look like?

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
```

I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I tried exactly that prior to posting this question, and it didn't work. That's when I figured that was more going on than I knew. 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin/
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a simplified form for the rewriting rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule !^admin/ index.php [NC,L]
```

This incorporates Matthew's suggestion of checking the path against `/admin/` (in `.htaccess` files you omit the leading slash).

You might also need to use a

```
RewriteBase /
```

before the first `RewriteCond` line.

Comment: I gave that a try, but unfortunately it didn't work (unless I removed the .htaccess file from the admin folder). 

Also, removing "RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]" breaks the rewrite.

Comment: It no longer redirected requests to the index.php file. They all just 404'd.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the pattern `!^admin/`. You could try changing it to `.*` (i.e. match everything) just as a test to see what happens.

Comment: Naw, the rule works perfectly, just not when there's a .htaccess auth file in the "admin/" folder. It's really got me baffled.

Answer (score 0):

If you gots mod_dir running on the server which adds prevailing forwardslashes/ when your rewrite rule conflicts with a folder such as mydomain/mypage/foldername the mod_dir slaps a forwardslash on the end of foldername/ as it is a real dir, if your rules specify in the htaccess to not follow indexes (Options -Indexes) and there is nothing in the folder then your rules will be ok, if there is something in the folder other than an index then expect this to happen to your url: mydomain/mypage/foldername/?request=mypage/foldername

As this is the default configuration of cPanel the issue is not your fault, it is a massive conflict in teh configuration that enables hackers to identify script requests and directory structures.

I do not have any solution if you are unable to disable multiviews in the http.conf of the server as most htacces solutions result in a redirect loop.

This is an unreported conflict/bug to cPanel so dont hold your breath for a solution, a workarround could be to nest your wntire project in a single folder and call pages internally.