# mod_rewrite not working due to mod_auth?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-auth

I must have discovered a bug in Apache! Because I have the wierdest issue with my webhost. I cannot access a folder named admin. It works in one virtualhost but not the other. (Same hosting account)

**/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # No logic for resolved paths
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/admin/.htaccess:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Resolving http://www.mydomain.com/admin/index.php I get 404 not found. If I remove the admin/.htaccess file the page resolves. What's up with that?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144401/htaccess-mod-rewrite-conflicting-with-subfolder-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem derives from the ErrorDocument setting.
Adding the following line to admin/.htaccess solves the problem

`ErrorDocument 401 "Access Denied"`

Answer (score 0):

See my [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules).  Unless oyu've overridden the defaults with on of the `RewriteOptions Inherit*` directives, then because the `/admin/.htaccess` exists then the parent one won't be executed.  Either add

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

to this file or simply repeat the rewrites that you need in the admin access file.

Comment: But the admin folder do not necessarily need any rewriting as it is a physical destination. What seems to be the case is the parent one is the one that is parsed. Isn't it odd how one Virtualhost works and the other does not?

Comment: You can get all sorts of weird effects if you have multiviews enabled by default.   Try replicating the -d, -f -l escape in your admin .htaccess